# How do I use the result of a fit as a normal function?

Tags: matlab, function

I'm new, so please forgive my naivety. I have a very simple code, which takes in a simple two-column csv file of data, as follows:

```
uiopen('*.csv')

x = VarName1;
y = VarName2;

Esq = fit( x, y, 'smoothingspline' );
figure
plot( Esq, x, y )

Conc = exp( -Esq )
```

Everything works except the last step. I'm able to plot the fit function, but for some reason when I define another function in terms of Esq (that is, Conc), it doesn't work, and can't be plotted. Help?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to apply a function that accepts a matrix as input to `Esq`, which is a [`fit object`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fit.html).

If you simply pass your `x` values to `Esq`, you will obtain a vector that can be used as input to `exp` to get the `Conc` values:

```
Conc = exp( -Esq(x) );
```

Note however that this solution does not modify your fit object, nor creates a new function. `Conc` above is a vector.

Answer (score 1):

You have to evaluate your [`cfit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/feval.html) object at certain points, e.g. `Conc = exp(-Esq(x));`. Alternatively, you can define an [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) like this:

```
Conc = @(x) exp( -Esq(x))
```

which you can then evaluate on arbitrary data:

```
plot(x, Conc(x));
```